# Submit a form without a submit button in Lynx?

Tags: lynx

There's a form on a website that looks like this:

```
<form action="/some_action">
<input type="radio" name="opt" value="1"> Option 1
<input type="radio" name="opt" value="2"> Option 2
<input type="radio" name="opt" value="3"> Option 3
</form>
```

In graphical browsers, some JavaScript is bound to the form which submits it when one of the radio buttons is selected. Lynx docs say you can submit a form by moving to a submit button and pressing <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but there's no submit button. Those keys only select an option and show an error message if pressed twice. Key <kbd>x</kbd> doesn't work either, it is intended for submit buttons and links.

Is there a way to submit this form in Lynx?

My Lynx version is 2.8.7rel.1

Answer (score 2):

The way the form is structured, no there is no way to submit it in Lynx. Why? Lynx does not support Javascript.